# Disable an Apple TV’s ability to be airplayed audio to only

Tags: macos, ios, audio, appletv, airplay

I never AirPlay audio to our Apple TV, but instead use a receiver with AirPlay capabilities. The AirPlay list is therefore crowded with an option that is never used and is only there to confuse. We do sometimes use AirPlay mirroring from another device.

Is it possible to disable the AirPlay audio features only on the Apple TV? Or as a secondary alternative, being able to hide the Apple TV from the audio sharing menu from the devices (I assume it’s more doable on macOS than iOS).